# How to trigger ng-change in directive test in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following AngularJS directive that creates an `input` element. Input has `ng-change` attribute that runs `doIt()` function. In my directive's unit test I want to check if `doIt` function is called when users changes the input. But the test does not pass. Though it works in the browser when testing manually.

Directive:

```
...
template: "<input ng-model='myModel' ng-change='doIt()' type='text'>"
```

Test:

```
el.find('input').trigger('change') // Dos not trigger ng-change
```

Live demo (ng-change): http://plnkr.co/edit/0yaUP6IQk7EIneRmphbW?p=preview

---

Now, the test passes if I manually bind `change` event instead of using `ng-change` attribute.

```
template: "<input ng-model='myModel' type='text'>",
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
  element.bind('change', function(event) {
    scope.doIt();
  });
}
```

Live demo (manual binding): http://plnkr.co/edit/dizuRaTFn4Ay1t41jL1K?p=preview

---

Is there a way to use `ng-change` and make it testable? Thank you.

Comment: ng-change is triggered on model changes, not events. why not just test the controller code for your "doIt" fn?

Comment: @marko, thanks for good question. All I want to do in directive's test is to check that doIt is called when user changes the input. doIt itself will be mocked in directive's test, because it is already tested in controller's test, as you suggested.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From your explanatory comment:

> All I want to do in directive's test is to check that `doIt` is called when user changes the input.

Whether or not the expression indicated by `ng-change` is correctly evaluated or not is really the responsibility of the `ngModel` directive, so I'm not sure I'd test it in this way; instead, I'd trust that the `ngModel` and `ngChange` directives have been correctly implemented and tested to call the function specified, and just test that calling the function itself affects the directive in the correct manner. An end-to-end or integration test could be used to handle the full-use scenario.

That said, you can get hold of the `ngModelController` instance that drives the `ngModel` change callback and set the view value yourself:

```javascript
it('trigger doIt', function() {
  var ngModelController = el.find('input').controller('ngModel');
  ngModelController.$setViewValue('test');
  expect($scope.youDidIt).toBe(true);
});
```

As I said, though, I feel like this is reaching too far into `ngModel`'s responsibilities, breaking the black-boxing you get with naturally composable directives.

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/BaWpxLuMh3HvivPUbrsd?p=preview

---

**[Update]**

After looking around at the AngularJS source, I found that the following also works:

```javascript
it('trigger doIt', function() {
  el.find('input').trigger('input');
  expect($scope.youDidIt).toBe(true);
});
```

It looks like the event is different in some browsers; `input` seems to work for Chrome.

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/rbZ5OnBtKMzdpmPkmn2B?p=preview

Here is the [relevant AngularJS code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/724819e3cfd8aeda1f724fb527db2b57494be9b7/test/ng/directive/inputSpec.js#L327-330), which uses the `$sniffer` service to figure out which event to trigger:

```javascript
changeInputValueTo = function(value) {
  inputElm.val(value);
  browserTrigger(inputElm, $sniffer.hasEvent('input') ? 'input' : 'change');
};
```

Even having this, I'm not sure I'd test a directive in this way.

Comment: Regarding the events, I think `input` is for text inputs and the like and `change` is for select boxes & radio buttons. At least that's what's working for me running tests on PhantomJS.

Comment: It seems browserTrigger is only present in angular-scenario.js. This means that it's only intended for e2e test, right? I am not able to use this function into a unit test, which is on purpose I believe.

Comment: @unludo Perhaps; my point was only that the AngularJS source was written to trigger a different event in certain browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I googled "angular directive trigger ng-change" and this StackOverflow question was the closest I got to anything useful, so I'll answer "How to trigger ng-change in a directive", since others are bound to land on this page, and I don't know how else to provide this information.

Inside the link function on the directive, this will trigger the ng-change function on your element:

```
element.controller('ngModel').$viewChangeListeners[0]();
```

`element.trigger("change")` and `element.trigger("input")` did not work for me, neither did anything else I could find online.

As an example, triggering the ng-change on blur:

```
wpModule.directive('triggerChangeOnBlur', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('blur', function () {
                element.controller('ngModel').$viewChangeListeners[0]();
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

I'm sorry that this is not directly answering OP's question. I will be more than happy to take some sound advice on where and how to share this information.

Comment: Ideally, you would ask a separate question and then answer it yourself (sounds weird, but it's encouraged).

I'm also looking for something that is not quite the OP, or your issue, and would find the answer faster if there were a question specifically about it.

Answer (score 1):

simple and it works
in your unit test env:

```
spyOn(self, 'updateTransactionPrice');


var el = compile('<form name="form" latest novalidate json-schema="main.schema_discount" json-schema-model="main._data"><input type="text" ng-model="main._data.reverse_discount" ng-class="{ \'form-invalid\': form.reverse_discount.$invalid }" ng-change="main.transactionPrice(form);" name="reverse_discount" class="form-control-basic" placeholder="" ng-disabled="!main.selectedProduct.total_price"></form>')(scope);
el.find('input').triggerHandler('change');

expect(self.updateTransactionPrice).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this simple line for long hours.
Just to save that in here.

How to select value from html-select, using Karma, and so get ng-change function working?

HTML:

Controller or directive JS:

```
  $scope.itemTypes = [{name: 'Some name 1', value: 'value_1'}, {name: 'Some name 2', value: 'value_2'}]

  $scope.itemTypeSelected = function () {
    console.log("Yesssa !!!!");
  };
```

Karma test fragment:

```
  angular.element(element.find("#selectedItemType")[0]).val('value_1').change();
  console.log("selected model.selectedItemType", element.isolateScope().model.selectedItemType);
```

Console:

```
'Yesssa !!!!'
'selected model.selectedItemType', 'value_1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have been trying to get this to work, but failed on every attempt. Finally concluded that my ng-model-options with a debounce setting on the onUpdate, was the problem.

If you have a debounce, make sure that you flush with the $timeout service. In angular mock, this timeout service has been extended with a flush operation, which handles all unfulfilled requests/actions.

```
    var tobetriggered = angular.element(element[0].querySelector('.js-triggervalue'));
    tobetriggered.val('value');
    tobetriggered.trigger('change');
    $timeout.flush();
```