# AngularJs : triggering an event to simulate user action when unit testing a directive

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have seen that in order to simulate user action on the DOM generated by a directive, there are two approaches, both trigering an event:

[How to trigger ng-change in directive test in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17626604/how-to-trigger-ng-change-in-directive-test-in-angularjs)

The first approach uses jquery and the second one a function called **browserTrigger** defined in **angular-scenario.js**. The second one is supposed to be better as jquery would have a bug on event triggering (which I believe, I am not arguing :) ).

Using the angular-scenario means e2e testing for me. but I have seen [egghead video](http://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-unit-testing-directive-scope)  and he seems to do unit testing. How is this possible ?

I guess he just copied the function ?

I think I am going to test directives as e2e tests, it makes more sense as unit test is more fore pure functions.

---

Well, I just found that browserTrigger is something internal not supposed to be used directly : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5178

---

Thanks!

Comment: I've tried to use `ngScenario` before in order to test a directive and found it trickier to use than just triggering events manually. Perhaps I haven't tried hard enough. Anyway, I've got the tests working with jQuery. You can check them out [here](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput/blob/master/test/tags-input.spec.js). Hopefully they can be useful to you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit test angular right-click directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720009/unit-test-angular-right-click-directive)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of 1.3.15 you can use triggerHandler to trigger a event as shown below,

```
it('should click the element',function(){
    element.triggerHandler('click') ;
    expect($scope.clicked).toBe(true);
});
```

Comment: It is also shown in at the same page for older versions

Comment: Is it possible to simulate a $scope.function() call?

Comment: I mean something like `<div ng-click="doSomething()"></div>`? For some reason I am absolutely unable to test this kind of behavior...

Answer (score 1):

simple and it works, example, in  unit test env:

```
spyOn(self, 'updateTransactionPrice');


var el = compile('<form name="form" latest novalidate json-schema="main.schema_discount" json-schema-model="main._data"><input type="text" ng-model="main._data.reverse_discount" ng-class="{ \'form-invalid\': form.reverse_discount.$invalid }" ng-change="main.transactionPrice(form);" name="reverse_discount" class="form-control-basic" placeholder="" ng-disabled="!main.selectedProduct.total_price"></form>')(scope);
el.find('input').triggerHandler('change');

expect(self.updateTransactionPrice).toHaveBeenCalled();
```